# Only serialize some specific properties of a class?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I ran into a problem with Json.Net.

My application is connected to a database and stores some data in it.
Lets assume my application has three different classes: Entity, Group, Organisation

Short look into Entity class:

```
public class Entity
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string UID { get; private set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public Gender EntityGender { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public Group EntityGroup { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public Organisation EntityOrganisation { get; set; }
```

Organisation and Group also have an ID property.
When serializing an Entity I do not want to fully serialize EntityGroup and EntityOrganisation but only their IDs.

Some quick example how I would like it to look like:

(How it looks now)

```
{
  "UID": "6c5204356b3a1a33",
  "Surname": "Bar",
  "Forename": "Foo",
  "EntityGroup": {
    "Name": "XGroup",
    "GroupOrganisation": {
      "Name": "FooOrg"
    }
  },
  "EntityOrganisation": null,
  "EntityStation": null
}
```

(How it should look like)

```
{
  "UID": "6c5204356b3a1a33",
  "Surname": "Bar",
  "Forename": "Foo",
  "EntityGroup": {
    "ID": 1,
    "GroupOrganisation": {
      "ID": 1
    }
  },
  "EntityOrganisation": null,
  "EntityStation": null
}
```

Is it possible to setup a JsonParser that only serializes the ID property of Group and Organisation when serializing an Entity?

Comment: What do you want to have happen with Organisation and Group when you deserialize?

Comment: I won't deserialize it directly. I'll parse it and load the corresponding Organisation / Group from database.
Maybe I'll do it in another way but that's my current idea :)

Comment: Or maybe I can use the solution of nick_w to simply load the Organisation/Group when deserializing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

In your `Entity` class, add the `JsonConverter` attribute to the `EntityGroup` class:

```
[JsonProperty]
[JsonConverter(typeof(EntityGroupConverter))]
public Group EntityGroup { get; set; }
```

This will use the `EntityGroupConverter` to serialize the `Group`. This class is as follows:

```
class EntityGroupConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Group);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Group group = value as Group;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, new { ID = group.ID,
            GroupOrganisation = new { ID = group.Organisation.ID } });
    }
}
```

The key here is using the `serializer` to write an anonymous object that includes only the desired properties.

Note that `ReadJson` is left unimplemented - I am assuming that deserialization is not required at this stage.

**Edit**

As Skadier pointed out, the signature of the `ReadJson` will look like this in more recent versions of Json.NET (the version used in this question is 3.5.0.0):

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
        object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
```

Comment: Thanks it works! :) I just had to correct your ReadJson() method because the parameters weren't correct.

Comment: @Skadier Glad it worked for you! I have edited my answer to mention your point about the `ReadJson` parameters.